# Keyboard events in the events page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible without using a content script to monitor keyboard events?
My background script:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
alert( "keyCode for the key pressed: " + e.keyCode + "\n" );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to monitor arbitrary keystrokes of a web page without [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

If you want to register a keyboard shortcut that can be triggered anywhere within the browser, use the [`chrome.commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands) API.